# Organize groups of aggregated data into a predefined list of rows, instead of all data points as separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I’m trying to create a dataset in SQL that will compile results for a treatment program.

I want to show the frequency of each Risk level broken down by Category, like this:

[image]

The SQL for that looks like this, with non-sensical dummy data inserted:

```
Select *
From 
 ( VALUES 
  ('Total Enrollments',5,9,3,2), 
  ('Total Successful',2,7,5,9),
  ('Total Failures',9,6,2,1),
  ('Failure - Drug Tests',2,1,4,7),
  ('Failure - Attendance Issues',2,6,9,2),
  ('Failure - Non-Payment',0,4,5,9),
  ('Failure - Other',3,9,3,1)
  ) t1 (Category,Low,Moderate,High,VeryHigh)
```

The ultimate purpose is to import the data to SSRS Report builder and probably PowerBI down the road and I'd rather do the aggregating and organizing in SQL since I HATE dealing with expressions in SSRS and I'd like the data to be as portable as possible for export to Excel, SSRS, PowerBI, whatever.

Performance is not a top concern as this report will run on our report server once a month and get auto-delivered to a list of individuals.

I currently have a query that lists all the data points I need, but they're all separate columns, meaning to organize it in SSRS would mean hand-creating a matrix.

So the query that fetches my million columns looks like this:

[image]

`--DECLARE
    --@StartDate and @EndDate variables will be passed in by SSRS

SELECT

--Males Enrolled during period, by risk level:
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.EnrollmentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesEnrollmentsLow,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.EnrollmentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Moderate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesEnrollmentsModerate,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.EnrollmentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesEnrollmentsHigh,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.EnrollmentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Very High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesEnrollmentsVeryHigh,

--Males Successful during period, by risk level:
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.SuccessDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesSuccessLow,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.SuccessDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Moderate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesSuccessModerate,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.SuccessDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesSuccessHigh,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.SuccessDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Very High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesSuccessVeryHigh,

--Males Failed during period, by risk level:
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesTotalFailLow,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Moderate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesTotalFailModerate,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesTotalFaillHigh,
Sum(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Very High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesTotalFailVeryHigh,

--Now break the failures down by reason:

--Males failed for FLDRUGTEST during period, by risk level:
SUM(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and tblProgramResults.ProgramCompletedReasonCode = 'FLDRUGTEST' and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesFailFLDRUGTESTLow,
SUM(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and tblProgramResults.ProgramCompletedReasonCode = 'FLDRUGTEST' and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Moderate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesFailFLDRUGTESTModerate,
SUM(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and tblProgramResults.ProgramCompletedReasonCode = 'FLDRUGTEST' and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesFailFLDRUGTESTHigh,
SUM(CASE WHEN clients.sex = 'M' and tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and tblProgramResults.ProgramCompletedReasonCode = 'FLDRUGTEST' and AssessmentResults.PanelRiskLevel = 'Very High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MalesFailFLDRUGTESTVeryHigh

--There are 3 other 'failure' reasons...

FROM
tblProgramResults
--Get the gender info for each client
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT
        Sex
        From tblClients
        WHERE tblClients.ClientID = tblProgramResults.ClientID
        ) Clients
--Get the assessment results for each client:
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT
        PanelRiskLevel
        from tblAssessmentResults
        WHERE tblAssessmentResults.clientID = tblProgramResults.ClientID
            ) AssessmentResults

WHERE
--We're only interested in male clients for now, there will be a separate table for females as they are evaluated on a different risk scale
Clients.sex = 'M'
--We only want to look through programs that had an Enrollment, a Successful Completion, or a Failure during the specified date range:
and (tblProgramResults.EnrollmentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate or
    tblProgramResults.SuccessDate between @StartDate and @EndDate or 
    tblProgramResults.FailDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
    )`

So how do I take the results of the large query and organize it into a nice table like the first picture instead of a ton of columns? I'm trying to plug the big query into the small one that creates the table but I'm just not getting anywhere. Or am I doing this the hard way when there's something way easier?

Answer (score 0):

if you know what all the columns are before hand you could just use the PIVOT function in t-sql.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

However, I would let SSRS, Power Bi or whatever do all that, pivoting data like that is what they are good at. I would transpose your query though using some basic grouping. The query would be much simpler too. I may have mis-understood so add a sample of your database tables data and expected outcome and I'll update the answer.

Taking the first part of query for example might be as simple as

```
SELECT c.sex, pr.EnrollmentDate, ar.PanelRiskLevel, Count(*) as EnrollmentCount
    FROM tblProgramResults pr
        JOIN tblClients c on pr.ClientID = c.ClientID
        JOIN tblAssessmentResults ar on pr.ClientID = ar.ClientID
    GROUP BY c.sex, pr.EnrollmentDate, ar.PanelRiskLevel
```

This could easily by pivoted in SSRS, Power NI etc.